Passing Cloudfare checking during web scraping on Java
Is that possible to pass Cloudfare test during scraping info from website? I used a lot of methods, but it didnt work. Cloudfare just stops me on it`s page.
I know that Bright Data API could pass Cloudfare checks, but its too expensive for me.
ChromeOptions chrome_options = new ChromeOptions();
chrome_options.addArguments("--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.246");
chrome_options.addArguments("--no-first-run");
chrome_options.addArguments("--force-color-profile=srgb");
chrome_options.addArguments("--metrics-recording-only");
chrome_options.addArguments("--password-store=basic");
chrome_options.addArguments("--use-mock-keychain");
chrome_options.addArguments("--export-tagged-pdf");
chrome_options.addArguments("--no-default-browser-check");
chrome_options.addArguments("--disable-background-mode");
chrome_options.addArguments("--enable-features=NetworkService,NetworkServiceInProcess," +
"LoadCryptoTokenExtension");
chrome_options.addArguments("--disable-features=FlashDeprecationWarning," +
"EnablePasswordsAccountStorage");
chrome_options.addArguments("--deny-permission-prompts");
chrome_options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");

ChromeDriver chromeDriver1 = new ChromeDriver(chrome_options);
    
chromeDriver1.get("URL WITH CLOUDFART");
Thread.sleep(10000);
System.out.println(chromeDriver1.getTitle());

Even using a lot of options and arguments didnt help. I`m just getting stucked on that page (see image)

if the site doesn't want bot-traffic (and probably specifically web-scraping) you should be a Good Internet Citizen™ and ask permission from the site owner. (they may have a public API you can use) Having said that, getting around bot-detection is a moving target and Cloudflare's "I'm under attack" mode is pretty good at it.  Probably the best way would be to automate at the OS level, not at browser-level.  (either a phone hooked up with something like ADB, or robot type framework for desktop OS)  That still might not get around behavior based detections.

You should also carefully read Terms of Service for the site.  If you do manage to get a fairly full collection of data, you may be at risk for being sued.... or even subject to penalties under DMCA laws if the site serves its own copyrighted content since you are trying to get around some protections here.  (IANAL, so take with a grain of salt)

it's something like a script to quickly sign up for warehouse shifts at my job(nothing illegal), so I don't think anyone will let me use the API :( . How can i do that in OS level? Would it work if i willrun it on server in the future?

for Java on desktop that would be Robot Framework, or for just about any platform Appium.
